# How to index malloc'd buffer and output

Tags: windows, assembly, buffer, nasm

See [full code here](http://pastebin.com/wgKd74Xh).

I have filled a buffer (malloc'd) with an `fread` call and it is a success. I am now trying to iterate over the buffer and commence parsing the input. I'm trying to start really simple by walking the buffer and output each char to the screen. But my loop is just outputting the entire input. Here is the loop portion of the code:

```
mov     ecx,    0
mov     ebx,    buffer
.readByte:
    push    DWORD   [ebx + 1 * ecx]
    push    DWORD   ecx
    push    DWORD   char
    call    _printf
    add     esp,        12

    incr    ecx

    cmp     ecx,        [fsz]
    jge     .endRead

    jmp     .readByte
```

The contents of the source file that is read in (s1.txt) is:

> 1 + 2;

My goal is to simply output:

> 1
>
> +
>
> 2
>   ;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you used `%s` format, which indicates a string, and that without a length specifier, why did you expect it to print just a single character? You should try `%c` format and something like `movzx eax, byte [ebx + ecx]; push eax` to pass the argument. A `%.1s` format specifier could also work and then you can keep your argument passing. Don't forget to add a newline too, if you want that. You could also just use `putchar` of course.

Oh, and `ecx` is a caller-saved register, as such any function you call may destroy its value. So if you want to keep using that, you need to save and restore it yourself.

Comment: Ok, so the call to `_printf` might corrupt it (`ecx` that is)? Makes sense. I'll change my formatting on the output. At least it looks like I was close. Thanks.

Comment: One other correct: `mov ebx, buffer` should be `mov ebx, [buffer]` and voila we have the output we need. 0: 1
1:
2: +
3:
4: 2
5: ;